# Red ribbon instead of messageboxes - silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to show custom messages in the red ribbon in silverlight? Is it a built in feature which can only be used in validation?

Comment: The built in validation system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  Anything returned by `GetErrors` will be displayed in the "red ribbon".  The way we do it, our class has a `List<string>` and a method `AddError`.  `AddError` adds a string to the list and raises the `ErrorsChanged` event.  `GetErrors` returns the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom Validation messages pretty easily with the [Silverlight Validator & Input Toolkit](http://silverlightvalidator.codeplex.com/)